# can't get compChoice to not return null

Tags: java, null

Here's the code I have for the core program itself:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class RockPaperScissors
{
private String playChoice;
private String compChoice;

public RockPaperScissors()
{



}

public RockPaperScissors(String player)
{
    playChoice = player;
}

public void setPlayers(String player)
{
    playChoice = player;
    compChoice = "";
    int num;
    num = (int) (Math.random()*3);
    switch(num)
    {
    case 0 : compChoice = "R";break;
    case 1 : compChoice = "P";break;
    case 2 : compChoice = "S";break;
    }
    
    System.out.println(num + " " + compChoice);
    out.print(compChoice);
}

public String determineWinner()
{
    String winner="";
    
    if(playChoice == "R")
    {
        switch(compChoice)
        {
        case "R" : winner = "!Draw Game!";break;
        case "P" : winner = "!Computer wins <<Paper Covers Rock>>!";break;
        case "S" : winner = "!Player wins <<Rock Breaks Scissors>>!";break;
        }
    }
    else if(playChoice == "P")
    {
        switch(compChoice)
        {
        case "R" : winner = "!Player wins <<Paper Covers Rock>>!";break;
        case "P" : winner = "!Draw Game!";break;
        case "S" : winner = "!Computer wins <<Scissors Cuts Paper>>!";break;
        }
    }
    else if(playChoice == "S")
    {
        switch(compChoice)
        {
        case "R" : winner = "!Computer wins <<Rock Breaks Scissors>>!";break;
        case "P" : winner = "!Player wins <<Scissors Cuts Paper>>!";break;
        case "S" : winner = "!Draw Game!";break;
        }
    }
    return winner;
}

public String toString()
{
    String output="";
    
    output = "player had " + playChoice + "\n computer had " + compChoice + "\n " + determineWinner();
    
    return output;
}
}
```

and here's my runner class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class Lab10d
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    char response  ;
    
    //add in a do while loop after you get the basics up and running
    
        String player = "";
    
        out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");
        
        //read in the player value
        player = keyboard.next();
    
        RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors(player);
        game.determineWinner();
        out.println(game);
    while(response.equals('y'))
    {
        out.print("Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon [R,P,S] :: ");
        player = keyboard.next();
        game.setPlayers(player);
        game.determineWinner();
        out.println(game + "\n");
        out.println("would you like to play again? (y/n):: ");
        response=  keyboard.next();
        
        
        
        
    }
    
}
}
```

here's an example of what should be resulting:

> Rock-Paper-Scissors - pick your weapon[R,P,S]:: R
>
> player had R
>
> computer had P
>
> !Computer wins <>!
>
> Do you want to play again? y

and if you put n for playing again, it stops.

main problem is getting compChoice to not say null

Comment: new issue, it's not liking my switch-case in the determineWinner() method

Comment: _it's not liking_ --> what does the compiler say exactly ??

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at RockPaperScissors.determineWinner(RockPaperScissors.java:68)
 at RockPaperScissors.toString(RockPaperScissors.java:82)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.println(Unknown Source)
 at Lab10d.main(Lab10d.java:27)

Comment: ^^^ that's after i give the scanner a value and hit enter

Comment: compChoice can be "", "R", "P", or "S" after calling setPlayers(). It can never 'return null'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in `main` method:

```
RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors(player);
game.determineWinner();
```

You initialize the `compChoice` String in the `setPlayers()` method, but that method is never called. Then you switch on `compChoice`, which is null, thus you get the `NullPointerException`.

This should fix your problem:

```
RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors(player);
game.setPlayers(player); // <-- insert this line.
game.determineWinner();
```

But be aware that you are not saving the String returned by `determineWinner()`, and then call `out.println(game);` which will call the `determineWinner()` method again...

Also this piece of your code

`while(response == response)`

will always be an endless loop, and i can't find a `break` statement in your loop.

Also **NEVER** compare Strings with `==`, use equals, google the explanation, there even are hundreds of SO explanations for that. So this

`if (playChoice == "R") // <-- WRONG`

should become this:

`if (playChoice.equals("R")) // <-- right`

or

`if ("R".equals(playChoice)) // <-- right`

Comment: Thank You!!! that solved the issue completely! Now, when I'm telling it whether or not to continue playing, response is a char but there's no way to read in a char from the user's input

Comment: `char c = yourString.charAt(0);`

Comment: `while(response.equals('y'))` <-- Wrong | correct --> `while(response.equals("y"))` because your response is a `String`

Comment: I've got it asking whether or not to play again but when I input a y, it does nothing

Comment: now you declare `char response  ;`, so it gets the dafault char value, but you only enter the loop if it equals `'y'`. If you want the loop to run at least once, you can use a `do-while` loop. But you write `response=  keyboard.next();` which will not compile, because `keyboard.next();` returns a `String` and you need a char. Look at 2nd comment to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

I just quickly go through your code, didn't actually test/run your code. But I found this:
Use the String equals method to compare strings, don't use == to compare strings.